# Oracle JSON_TABLE index on one of the "Virtual Column"

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    doc CLOB CONSTRAINT doc_valid_json CHECK (doc IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO customers
VALUES ('[
          {"REGION": "AMR", "CNTRY": "US"},
          {"REGION": "EUR", "CNTRY": "UK"}
         ]');

CREATE TABLE country_map
(
    code VARCHAR2(2), 
    description VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO country_map VALUES ('US', 'United States');
INSERT INTO country_map VALUES ('UK', 'United Kingdom');
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    region, code, description 
FROM 
    customers,
    JSON_TABLE(doc, '$[*]' COLUMNS 
           (
               row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
               region     VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.REGION',
               cntry      VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.CNTRY'
           )) t
JOIN 
    country_map m ON m.code = t.cntry;
```

On this query I will get full scan table on JOIN. Is there any way I can index my virtual column? Or is there a better way to reduce the JOIN cost?

```
| Id  | Operation               | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |             |     1 | 18421 |    99   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN              |             |     1 | 18421 |    99   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL     | COUNTRY_MAP |     1 |    30 |    35   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   NESTED LOOPS          |             |     1 | 18391 |    64   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | CUSTOMERS   |     1 | 18387 |    35   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    JSONTABLE EVALUATION |             |       |       |            |          |
```

Comment: That hash join to country_map doesn't have anything to do with your JSON work. It's simply Oracle's decision as to the best join method to a table with 0 or 1 rows in it (it doesn't know you inserted 2 rows because you haven't gathered stats), and it's actually right about that... you want that to be a hash join + full table scan. If there are more than 1 rows in it, you should gather stats on it, but given the name of the table it's still quite likely that a hash join + full scan is the best join method since its row count is going to be very low.

Comment: Please describe what optimization do you expect to happen. The plan is right in terms of current setup (and most probably with more rows according to table names: `map` is expected to be some decoding table with auxiliarry information and very low cardinality). Though it's inaccurate in number of rows with reasoning described in the comment above.

Comment: @PaulW, i have similar table with more data, full country list for example. The customers here is a new table, i am trying to see what is the behavior when I convert my conventional RDBMS table to store as JSON. The optimization I am trying to achieve is to let the similar cost being used when I use the traditional RDBMS which will have index on "cntry" column.

Comment: Don't pay any attention to cost, it isn't reliable. I promise there aren't enough countries in the world to need an index on your country table. Indexes are for when you want a tiny selection from a larger table, and "larger" is typically tens of thousands of rows at a bare minimum. Instead, tune only queries that are actually giving you trouble, and trust Oracle with the rest.

Comment: There are a limited number of countries in the world. Having 2-letter code for each and an average name of, say, 20 letters you'll need 22 chars per row on average. Having roughly 300 territory codes the entire table will consume 1 default-sized data block (8Kb) in single-byte charset and up to 4 data blocks in multi-byte charset, which will be read in nanoseconds. Index is not fast=true option, it is also stored in data blocks and have an overhead in access. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html